# How to solve this equation √288/√34 *18/√34

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, radicals, fractions

$\frac{\sqrt{288}}{\sqrt{34}}\cdot\frac{18}{\sqrt{34}}$

In the first fraction square root is for both $288$ and $24$ where as in second fraction it's only for $34$

Please help

Comment: Ok What 24? do you mean this $\frac{\sqrt{288}}{\sqrt{34}}*\frac{18}{\sqrt{34}}$?

Comment: This is no _equation_ and just use your calculator.

Comment: Aren't we doing your homework ?

Comment: @Winter I think the person wants an exact answer rather than a approximate one

Comment: I would bet that the denominator is actually $\sqrt{24}$ and not $\sqrt{34}$ since this would lead to the nicer result : $9 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: It is √34 only i know the answer which is 108√2/17 but can some one explain how can i solve it
actuall it whole root of √288/34 one big root symbol for whole of the fraction

Comment: @winter i need the way to solve it we arent allowed to use calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root of 288 can be written as 12√2 , as the square of 12 is 144.
The product of root 34 into root 34 would be 34.
And Hence substitute the value of root 2 into the equation to compute the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped.